# parse error in R while evaluating an expression

Tags: r

I received the following error while running the below mentioned code in jupyter notebook

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:6:12: unexpected input
5: 
6: z <- (xbar <e2>
              ^
Traceback:
```

The code:

```
xbar <- 9900            # sample mean 
mu <- 10000            # hypothesized value 
sigma <- 120            # population standard deviation 
n <- 30                 # sample size 

z <- (xbar − mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `−` (minus sign) in your example looks like it might actually be the en dash character. Here is the character in your example, followed by the standard keyboard dash/hyphen character: −, -.

If you delete that character and type the standard dash character, does the code run as expected?

Here's a reproduction of your error in a regular R session. The first version is your original code. In the second, I've replaced the en dash with a standard dash. I haven't used code formatting below, because the two dashes look exactly the same after going through the code formatter.

> (xbar − mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
>   Error: unexpected input in "(xbar �"
>
> (xbar - mu)/(sigma/sqrt(n))
>   [1] -4.564355